# Change DateTime format when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

How to change the `DateTime` format when using Entity Framework?

In my database table, the column `sb_ActivityDate` is of 'datetime' datatype.

[image]

Here is how I get that column's value:

```
var query = context.CPDActivities.AsQueryable();

if (!(member.MemberID == Guid.Empty))
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.sb_MemberContactId == member.MemberID).OrderBy(e=>e.sb_ActivityDate).ThenBy(e => e.CreatedOn);
} 
else
{
    return null;
}
```

And stepping through the code can see that the 'sb_ActivityDate' value is now in M/d/yyyy format where I need dd/MM/yyyy.

[image]

The property for the date created by Entity Framework database first:

```
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> sb_ActivityDate { get; set; }
```

Edit 1: my system date format:

[image]

Edit 2:

- Visual Studio 2017
- .Net version 4.5.1

Edit 3:

[image]

Edit 4:

Added a simple test textbox with date:

```
tb_dateTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

[image]

This seems to show the CMS culture is not causing the issue.  Something else is formatting the date.

Comment: Datetime values don't have a format, that's only relevant when you display the values to a user. What is shown in SSMS and Visual Studio debug will depend on system settings. You should not care about these.

Comment: Outisde of using EF I would just format the value coming out of the database and into my property.  Due to how EF works I don't have that control (it just maps the DB object to the EF model), can I change the regional culture within the project?

Comment: As I said, the value has no inherent format. If you are not providing explicit formats it will use the format of your system.

Comment: `And stepping through the code can see that the 'sb_ActivityDate' value is now in M/d/yyyy format where I need dd/MM/yyyy.` `datetime` **does not have a format**. How it displays in the debugger is a complete irrelevance - it is stored under the covers as a numeric value with no 'format'. Is your question really 'how do I convert this `datetime` to a `string` based on this format?

Comment: @Agamemnon `DateTime` has no format in .NET or any database product. They are just binary values. You *don't* need to hard-code the culture anywhere. If you make sure you use the correct types in the database and your code, use parameterized queries and only format dates on the *UI*, you'll be able to handle all locales without any code changes

Comment: @Agamemnon if you want to *display* dates in a specific style, you should either specify the *client's* locale or specify the format string on the UI itself. EF has nothing to do with the UI. That's why mjwills asks what app it is - that's the *most important* question. Desktop apps pick the end user's locale settings. Web applications start witht the *browser's* preferred languages. In all cases .NET tries to determine the correct locale at the UI layer

Comment: @Agamemnon internationalizing/localizing the UI is so fundamental that it's described in each stack's docs, tutorials and certification tests. If you explain which stack you use, people will be able to point to the correct docs, tutorials. You may not have to do anything at all

Comment: @Agamemnon for example, if, like most developers, you use a US locale in your machine, you'll see dates as US dates, but your business users will still see UK-style dates because that's *their* locale. The same with web apps - their preferred language probably *won't* be `en-US`

Comment: @Agamemnon no, VS doesn't change the cutlure. We developers do. And you still haven't explained what app you build or how you format strings. The important parts are still missing. You haven't posted any code or screenshot that shows date to string conversions

Comment: @Agamemnon unless you confuse the watch window's display for some a date format or changed locale? As people have already said, dates have no format. VS is a desktop application too and has to format strings for display though. It uses the InvariantCutlure which..... uses the US format for dates. That doesn't mean the date has changed, or that your application will display anything this way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF grabs the date from the DB which is in the correct 'format'.  It maps the date to a property in a model that EF created.  I have then bound the values of that model to a table.  What results is a date which is not in the format I need.

Comment: `EF grabs the date from the DB which is in the correct 'format'.` **There is no 'format'.** Your process' culture (and thus the format it uses when **converting** the `datetime` to a `string`) is not what you want it to be - that is all. Either the OS culture is set incorrectly, or your code has set the culture incorrectly.

Comment: Please confirm (from checking in IIS) what user account the app pool is running under and share that with us. _Please do not guess._

Comment: @mjwills This is a web application.  I am compliling the project and installing it as a module to a CMS on my local machine but it connects to the live database.  It test it on a browser on my own machine.

Comment: Are you (or the CMS) doing anything in code to override / set the app's culture? Which CMS are you using? Does the problem go away if you reboot your PC?

Comment: @mjwills the OP's screenshots only show watch variables. The OP seems to be asking why VS displays *watch variables* in the US format. *Some* duplicates say that the system's locale is used in the watch variables, some say it's not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just confirmed it is dd/mm/yyyy on my machine (`Watch` and `Immediate` - same windows the OP shows).

Comment: @mjwills mine too, which means this is app-and-version-specific behavior. That's why answers a single year apart contradict each other. I'd bet there's a duplicate that says `change this setting in the debug options`. It doesn't affect the application, just the debugger though.

Comment: I'd bet $100 the OP's CMS is setting the culture @PanagiotisKanavos. Or something weird like the app pool user has a different culture.

Comment: @mjwills you'd win! The *CurrentCulture*, but *not* the `CurrentUICulture` affects the debugger too. So this *is* a `what's your app, where's the culture set` question after all

Comment: @mjwills I was so sure you were going to be right about the CMS's culture being wrong but I have checked on my local instance (en-UK) and have even installed the module on our live website (also en-UK) where other dates are shown correctly, but the date is still showing in US format.  I will strip my project back and keep looking for clues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem relates to regional/culture settings, and it seems the ones Visual Studio is working under are not the same as the database. Since VS2015, you can check what format the debugger will be working under by checking the value for `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

If you want to format the date/time to something specific for displaying the date/time, such as from a web application where typically users could have different culture settings, then you need to convert it to a string at the point you're displaying the date/time.

Comment: Can I not just change the culture somewhere?  Within Visual Studio or some Entity Framework settings/properties?

Comment: Visual Studio uses the regional settings from Windows, but really it's always a good idea to format the date into a string at the point where you're displaying it.

Comment: My system is based in teh UK and displayed dd/MM/yyyy for everything else.  I have just added screen shot showing my system's data format settings

Comment: Converting dates to strings *caused* the problem in the first place. `DateTime` has no format in .NET. The date types used in databases have no formats either. The way to fix the problem is to *not* convert anything to a string

Comment: @Agamemnon don't use strings. Countries throughout Europe use different date layouts and yet *don't* have to hard-code formats, or use different formats for each country. They do so by *not* usings strings to store dates

Comment: What does your Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture say @Agamemnon? And what version of Visual Studio are you using? Since VS2015, all date formats in debugger should be formatted according to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture which is generally the same as the Windows regional settings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, clearly he is not storing strings, and is processing using datetime. However it would be advisable to convert to string at the point he will be displaying the date, especially so if working on a web application.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti in that case you should rephrase the answer to `you should format something to a string only when you need to display it in a specific way`

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Interestingly my current culture is showing as en-US.... this must be what's causing my issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, did so.

Comment: @Agamemnon, are you setting the application's culture anywhere?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti The only place I can see any reference toe he culture is in the webconfig for the entityFramework section:     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561884e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not storing/changing the date anywhere along the line.  I am using EF to grab the data from the DB, map it to the model EF created and then binding it directly to the display table.  No formatting anywhere.

Comment: @Agamemnon in this case you're asking why the *watch window* displays dates the way it does. This has nothing to do with EF. That's how VS works - it uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and the project's language to display numbers and dates. You can't change that nor should you have to

Comment: @Agamemnon, I really don't think you *NEED* to do anything at all, but if you absolutely must hard-code your culture, then you can set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to the ones you want. That should show you the dates in the debugger in UK, but please understand that if this will hard-code it for all users.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think you can change that by changing the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. Whether or not one should be encouraged to do that is a completely separate argument.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I don't want any 'hacky' work around.  It seems I have probably (inadvertantly) asked the wrong question.  My gridview is databound to the EF model.  I have gone textBox.text = object.property.ToString();  I have no formatting anywhere.  When running, the web application it shows the wrong date format for me.

Comment: `I have gone textBox.text = object.property.ToString(); I have no formatting anywhere.` Specify the format you want inside the `ToString` call @Agamemnon.

Comment: @mjwills sorry, that should have set "Have NOT gone..." Also, I am looking into the CMS culture now, you may be on to something.  Still confused about the VS debugging showing US and not system...